# Is there a way of column-based ArrayReshape

Tags: list-manipulation

I have checked the official document of ArrayShape of Wolfram Language. I am wondering is there a column-based way to do ArrayReshape?

Let me give a simple example,
if I run

```
ArrayReshape[Range[10],{2,5}]
```

I get {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8, 9, 10}}.

What if I want to reshape Range[10] as {{1,3,5,7,9},{2,,4,6,8,10}}?

In R language, I just need to set byrow = FALSE , is there a similar way in Mathematica to do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
Transpose[ArrayReshape[Range[10], Reverse[{2, 5}]]]
(*{{1, 3, 5, 7, 9}, {2, 4, 6, 8, 10}}*)
```

Answer (score 7):

Answer using `ArrayShape` is given.

But it is also possible to just use `Patition`.  I know you did not ask for this, but I think it is simpler for what output you wanted.

```
Transpose[Partition[Range[10], 2]]
```

gives

```
{{1, 3, 5, 7, 9}, {2, 4, 6, 8, 10}}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
Extract[Range@10, {{1 ;; ;; 2}, {2 ;; ;; 2}}]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list = Range[10];

Query[{1 ;; ;; 2, 2 ;; ;; 2}] @ list
```

{{1, 3, 5, 7, 9}, {2, 4, 6, 8, 10}}

```
Values @ GroupBy[EvenQ] @ list
```

{{1, 3, 5, 7, 9}, {2, 4, 6, 8, 10}}

Comment: (+1) Nice way to use `GroupBy` :-)